# Nginx with Clean Urls, Get Parameters, and PHP-FPM

Tags: get, nginx, clean-urls, php

I was curious to know if it was possible to somehow configure nginx so that it will parse url arguments without specifying `.php` at the end of the filename before the arguments are sent.

For example, let's say I have an account module which processes which aspect of the account to load, based on the argument sent. If the argument is `?sk='login'`, it will load the login module. If it is `?sk='register'`, it will load the registration module - and so on and so forth.

The problem is that when I type `http://host/account?sk='login'`, I do not get anything via `$_GET` when I try to print the values within the array. The thing is that the clean URL *does* load the file which is supposed to manage the `$_GET` arguments, except it will not actually *process* `$_GET` unless I specify `.php` at the end of the filename.

I'm guessing there's an nginx or php-fpm configuration somehow which allows this.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is `account` actually `account.php`, or is there a front controller at `index.php`, which handles URL routing?

Comment: it's actually `account.base.php`, but nginx handles the url rerouting via `location` blocks.

Comment: @hakre care to spread the love and show how it's done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

The idea, with nginx, is to define a location, specify that location's root, and then do a `try_files` while specifying the `$uri` variable and the `.php` file to execute, *with* the arguments.

For example:

```
location /somelocation {
    root /path/to/somelocation/on/server;
    try_files $uri /somelocation/somefile.php?key=$args;
}
```

Rather than typing `http://host/somelocation?key='someargument'`, you would specify `/somelocation?someargument`

From there on, when you call `$_GET[ 'key' ]` in your php, it will output `someargument` with a key of `key`. The key can be whatever you specify.

Comment: Be sure to read this before implementing this answer https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block